# Logic for importing two different versions of modules based on dependencies?

Tags: python-2.7, module

This is the structure of my module:

```
PyTurtle3D/
    __init__.py
    shape.py
    turtle_core/
        __init__.py
        wireframe.py
    pygame_core/
        __init__.py
        wireframe.py
    cube.py
    tetrahedron.py
```

The WireFrame classes defined in each of the two core modules are both subclasses of the Shape class at the top level. The Cube and Tetrahedron classes are subclasses of whichever Wireframe class I can use, preferring the pygame one. Is there some magic I could do in the `__init__.py` files to make this happen?

this is what I tried in the `__init__.py` file in PyTurtle3D (the other two are blank.):

```
try:
    import pygame
except:
    import turtle_core as core
else:
    import pygame_core as core
finally:
    WireFrame = core.wireframe.WireFrame
```

but python is saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wireframe'`.

Also, before I made two separate implementations of wireframe.py, I had these sort of lines at the top of my cube.py and tetrahedron.py files:

```
from wireframe import WireFrame

class Cube(WireFrame):
    ...
```

How do I do this now? Should I just keep all of the different implementations together, and  just check for pygame at the top of each class that is different? It would be cool if I didn't have to change cube.py or tetrahedron.py at all.

The only way I can think of to not have to check for pygame everywhere is to have constants.py file that I modify in the top `__init__.py` file when I check for pygame, that all the other files import. But that feels really hackish.

Comment: Should be possible, but you have to try it yourself and show us where you get stuck before you'll get much help on stackoverflow.  I imagine I'd start with `try: import pygame` and `except ImportError:` logic in a file at the top level of the file hierarchy.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As per your updated question:
You can't do

```
from _core.wireframe import WireFrame
```

in python. Module core is already imported so you could do:

```
Wireframe = _core.wireframe.Wireframe
```

to get the desired wireframe.

OLD:

I suppose you could do something like:

```
try:
     import pygame
except:
     print("Module not found")
     import custommodule
     import subclass2
```

I am not sure whether there is a better way to do it, but this will most certainly work.